# Why will Jupyter Notebook open from WSL but not MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm, jupyter-notebook

So I've installed and gotten Jupyter notebook to work quite well from WSL on my computer. I created a alias called `juno` which launches Jupyter notebook in my local browser. As of recently I've needed to be able to launch Jupyter Notebook from MobaXterm (non WSL environment), but whenever I launch from this environment my browser always says:

> This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.

Does anyone have an idea how to be able to launch Jupyter notebook from my normal windows environment?